# Cannot update Eclipse after Updating SDK Tools

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

so I recently updated my SDK Tools to revision 21. After doing so I went to update Eclipse but halfway through the update I get the following error:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>
> Unable to read repository at
>   https://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/content.xml. Remote host
>   closed connection during handshake
>
> Unable to read repository at
>   https://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/content.xml. Remote host
>   closed connection during handshake
>
> I went to both URLs and got the following error:
>
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a
>   problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have.
>
> Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

I'm wondering if the root of the problem is with the SSL or the the XML editor I'm using because I've had previous problems reading XML files from other repositories.

Help! Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Safe to say it is their SSL connection.

Sources: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/https://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/content.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because your eclipse cannot make SSL connection with the server, check if you have any antivirus/firewalls that block SSL connections.